# XML -> DOM -> Modify -> String

Tags: java, android

I am coding an Android client that talks to some web services via XML packets.
A typical packet looks like this..

```
<Packet service="login">
  <username></username>
  <password></password>
</Packet>
```

I have about 20 of these packets and would like to store them in my resources maybe in res/xml or res/raw

I want to store these 'empty' packets and load them using XML DOM and then fill in the content between the tags or attributes but am unsure how to do this.

Once the DOM packet has been filled in I want to get that back as a String so that I can send the packet to the server.

So to summarize my questions are..

(1) How do I load an XML resource using DOM?

(2) How do I convert the DOM object to a String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `javax.xml.parsers.*`, `org.xml.sax.*`, `org.w3c.dom.*`, `org.xmlpull.v1.*` packages for full XML support on Android. Here's a tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from xml to DOM is done by a XML Parser, common helper libraries are jdom or dom4j. You feed a stream to the parser and the result is (if the xml is OK) a DOM document.

The other way round is done with a XMLOutputter. That's basically a writer which takes a DOM document (or a node) and writes xml to a stream. jdom and dom4j both contain such a writer.

Use `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream` to convert between streams and String.

Comment: I would prefer to do this with classes already present in Android if possible without using external libraries.
Android comes with standard DOM support but I am unfamiliar with them as I generally prefer to use SAX